# second router in my network

Tags: router, lan, wan

I've got a modem with a built-in router that has DHCP enabled and should be the "primary router", which is on 192.168.1.1

Because the wireless signal of the above router was too weak upstairs I bought another TP-Link router for upstairs, now I want to configure the new one to extend my primary router's wifi signal.

So, I followed a tutorial, turned off the DHCP server for the new router and on the first router I removed an IP from it's DHCP range ( 192.168.1.2 ). The next step would be to assign the unassigned IP to the new router but how should I assign this? Once I go to the network tab in my new router's configuration webpage it shows me a WAN IP and a LAN IP, the LAN IP is defaulted to 192.168.0.1 and the WAN IP is set to "Dynamic IP", once I plug an ethernet cable from the primary router to the new one's WAN port it obtains a WAN IP automatically, is this supposed to happen? Which of the 2 should I chance to be 192.168.1.2?

Thank you

Comment: Why are you connecting the primary router to the new one's WAN port? They're on the same LAN. The WAN port is for a WAN connection, not a LAN connection.

Comment: Indeed, as @DavidSchwartz mentions, you should assign 192.168.1.2 as the LAN IP on the TP-Link.